# field type mapping error in CONSTRUCT SPARQL query

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, virtuoso

I am trying to check whether the literal value of this triple: `<resource1> skos:altSymbol "literal values of resource2"` exists as resource `<resource2>` in my endpoint.
If yes I would like to construct a new triple `<resource1> predicate <resource2>`.

I run the following query but got an error.

I don't know what is wrong with the query. If someone can help me or suggest me a different way to proceed. It could be great!

Thanks
Pierre

**Sparql Endpoint**: http://agrold.southgreen.fr/sparql

*System is OpenLink Virtuoso 7.2.5 opensource (linux)*

```
BASE <http://www.southgreen.fr/agrold/>
PREFIX      rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX     rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX     skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
PREFIX      xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX    vocab: <vocabulary/>
PREFIX resource: <resource/>
PREFIX      obo: <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/>
PREFIX      sio: <http://semanticscience.org/resource/>

CONSTRUCT { ?protein_id sio:SIO_000339 ?existURI . }
WHERE
  {
    ?protein_id ?p             ?o      ;
                rdfs:label     ?label  ;
                skos:altSymbol ?symbol ;
                obo:RO_0002162 <http://identifiers.org/taxonomy/39947> .
    BIND ( CONCAT ( str ( resource: ) , str ( ?symbol ) ) AS ?uri)
    FILTER IF ( EXISTS { ?uri rdf:type vocab:Gene } , ?uri , "None" )
    BIND ( URI ( ?uri ) as ?existURI )
   }
LIMIT 100
```

returning error = `Virtuoso 37000 Error SP031: SPARQL compiler: Internal error: sparp_check_field_mapping_spo(): field is neither variable nor literal?`

Comment: and what is not working? I tried your query in the web UI, it works. Or not?

Comment: I mean, of course the query is not correct. You bind just a string to `?uri`. A literal can never be the subject of a triple, thus checking `?uri rdf:type vocab:Gene` is invalid. And you can simply put the IF into the BIND, the FILTER is useless. Or I'm misunderstanding your query?

Comment: is this what you want?: `CONSTRUCT {?protein_id sio:SIO_000339 ?existURI.}
WHERE {
      {select ?protein_id ?uri {
      ?protein_id ?p ?o;
      rdfs:label ?label ;
      skos:altSymbol ?symbol;
      obo:RO_0002162  <http://identifiers.org/taxonomy/39947>  .
      BIND(URI(CONCAT(str(resource:),str(?symbol))) as ?uri) 
      }}
      
      BIND(If(EXISTS{?uri rdf:type vocab:Gene}, ?uri, "None" ) as ?existURI)

}
LIMIT 100` - I'm not sure about the output. But without subquery there is some issue with the BIND order

Comment: ok, wrapping it into a separate graph pattern also works: `CONSTRUCT {?protein_id sio:SIO_000339 ?existURI.}
WHERE {
      
      {?protein_id ?p ?o;
      rdfs:label ?label ;
      skos:altSymbol ?symbol;
      obo:RO_0002162  <http://identifiers.org/taxonomy/39947>  .
      BIND(URI(CONCAT(str(resource:),str(?symbol))) as ?uri) }
    
      
      BIND(If(EXISTS{?uri rdf:type vocab:Gene}, ?uri, "None" ) as ?existURI)

}
LIMIT 100` - so, no need for a subquery

Comment: It's True ! i can't reproduce the error now.

Comment: Thanks your query is working ! Indeed this is what i want.

Answer (score 0):

As seen in comments, this query revision resolves the issue --

```
CONSTRUCT
   { ?protein_id sio:SIO_000339 ?existURI . } 
WHERE
  {
    { ?protein_id ?p             ?o ;
                  rdfs:label     ?label ;
                  skos:altSymbol ?symbol ;
                  obo:RO_0002162 <http://identifiers.org/taxonomy/39947> .
      BIND ( URI ( CONCAT ( str ( resource: ) , str ( ?symbol ) ) ) AS ?uri)
    }
    BIND ( If ( EXISTS { ?uri rdf:type vocab:Gene } , ?uri , "None" ) AS ?existURI )
  } 
LIMIT 100
```